# Passing object of class/constructor errors

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing the implementation file of a program I'm doing. I included the header file in it which is why you don't see as much as you would usually see

This is the program in which all the functions you see are included in a class called "Body". The member functions are public except for the `std::istream` which is considered "friend" and the variables are private

I'm trying to understand why I am getting this error:

> "passing const Body as 'this' argument of double Body::getX() discards qualifiers"

This error is pointing to my `distanceTo` function that I wrote. I kind of understand what the error message is saying but I really need the passing argument of `distantTo` function to be constant. Any way of fixing this?

This is the overall view of my program:

```
#include "Body.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>


Body::Body(std::string _name, double _mass, double _x, 
    double _y, double _vx, double _vy)
{
    name = _name;
    mass = _mass;
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    vx = _vx;
    vy = _vy;
}

double Body::getX()
{
    return x;
}

double Body::getY()
{
    return y;
}

double Body::getVX()
{
    return vx;
}

double Body::getVY()
{
    return vy;
}

double Body::getMass()
{
    return mass;
}

void Body::setX(double _x)
{
    x = _x;
}

void Body::setY(double _y)
{
    y = _y;
}

void Body::setVX(double _vx)
{
    vx = _vx;
}

void Body::setVY(double _vy)
{
    vy = _vy;
}

void Body::draw(Canvas &canvas)
{
    canvas.DrawCircle(getX(), getY(), 10);
    canvas.DrawText(getX()+2, getY(), name);
}


istream &Body::operator>>(std::istream &input, Body &body)
{

    input >> body.name >> body.mass >> body.x >> body.y >> body.vx >> body.vy;

    return input;

}


double Body::distanceTo(const Body &other)
{
    double tx = x-other.getX(); 
    double ty = y-other.getY();
    double ans = sqrt(tx*tx + ty *ty);

    return ans;
}

double Body::forceX(double G, const Body &body)
{
    double d = distanceTo(body);
    double d3=d*d*d;
    double tx = x - getX();
    double dx= sqrt( tx * tx );
    double fx = G * ((mass * getMass() * dx) / d3);

    return fx;      
}

double Body::forceY(double G, const Body &body)
{
    double d = distanceTo(body);
    double d3=d*d*d;
    double ty = y - getX();
    double dy= sqrt( ty * ty );
    double fy = G * ((mass * getMass() * dy) / d3); 

    return fy;  
}
```

Private data:

```
std::string name;
double x, y;
double vx, vy;
double mass;
```

Comment: To put it in other words, you can't call a non-const function on a const object.

Comment: Little side note, using _ infront of your variables is bad practice in most cases.

Comment: okay i understand the mistake now

Comment: @Need4Sleep - it's a bad idea for function variables, only because the underscore is often used to indicate it's a member variable of the class, so this will probably confused people.

Answer (score 1):

Make your get member functions constant, nothing changes in these functions and will allow your distance function to work as expected

```
double getX() const;
double getY() const;
```

To clarify, as chris pointed out in the comments you cannot call a non-const function with a constant object. You promised the compiler the object would not change what so ever, so you need to provide constant functions to make the compiler happy.